# Partition Generating Functions

Tags: generating-functions, integer-partitions

Prove the following identity by counting two sets of partitions in two different ways.

\begin{equation}\prod_{i\geq 0}(1+x^{2i+1})=1 + \sum_{n\gt 0}x^{n^2}\prod_{j=1}^n\frac{1}{1-x^{2j}}.\end{equation}

I know the partition on the left side, it's the number of partitions with $i$ distinct odd parts. I just need help doing the right side. The second part of the second term , the product is the number of partitions of $n$ and for each $i$, the parts of size $i$ occur an even number of times.
Now it's being multiplied by the summations of $x^{n^2}$ times. How would that effect the partition?

Comment: The $[x^k]$ coefficient of the product would be the number of partitions of $k$ with parts $\le n$ each occurring an even number of times.  Multiplying by $x^{n^2}$ then shifts to the $[x^k]$ coefficient being the number of partitions of $k - n^2$ with this property.

Comment: The generating function is of OEIS sequence [A000700](http://oeis.org/A000700). It is also the number of partitions that are [self-conjugate](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Self-ConjugatePartition.html). The [Ferers diagram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FerrersDiagram.html) of these partitions are sums of [gnomons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gnomon), and they also contain a maximal square portion with the rest consists of two pieces that are conjugate to each other.

Comment: It would be better to ask for clarification of the answers to the other question, one of which you accepted (!), than to ask the question again.

Comment: yes i realized i posted it twice, my apologies. but i thought i deleted the duplicate